# Call in a C# program a function from a dll library generated with IKVM with a List param

Tags: c#, jar, ikvm

Everything is in the title. I generated a dll file from a jar which I included in my C# project. I try to call a function from the library that take a java.util.List in param but I can't use it and I wonder if there's a workaround for that. I also added the IKVM.OpenJDK.Util.dll to my project but it's still the same issue. Hope someone could help, thank's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add "using java.util;" and work with java.util.List objects...